# Divide two Prometheus metrics that don't have the same dimension set?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm trying to get the average of some prometheus metric (`kafka_commit_latency`) per kubernetes pod. My approach was to get the sum of `kafka_commit_latency` and to divide it by the number of kubernetes pods for my application, so here are the variables I derived and the overall expression:

- Sum of desired metric (kafka commit latencies) across my application: `sum(kafka_consumer_commit_latency_avg_seconds{application="my_app"})`
- No. of kubernetes pods for my application:
  `sum(node_namespace_pod:kube_pod_info:{pod=~".*my_app.*"})`
- Overall expression:
  `sum(kafka_consumer_commit_latency_avg_seconds{application="my_app"})/sum(node_namespace_pod:kube_pod_info:{pod=~".*my_app.*"})`

but the main issue here is that the two range vectors don't have anything common in the dimension set, so how can this division be made?

Answer (score 0):

For binary operators, you can use [grouping modifiers](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches). In your case, it would be `ON` without label list since you want to disregard all labels.

```
sum(kafka...) / ON() sum(node_...)
```